# How can you write a module for a role group?

Tags: types, module, polymorphism, raku

A feature of roles is role groups, which allow you to declare multiple roles with the same name accepting different parameters, similarly to multi routines:

```
role Foo[Int:D] {
    method is-int(::?CLASS:_: --> True)  { }
    method is-str(::?CLASS:_: --> False) { }
}
role Foo[Str:D] {
    method is-int(::?CLASS:_: --> False) { }
    method is-str(::?CLASS:_: --> True)  { }
}
```

Often, for one type, you have one module. The problem is you can only have one `unit` scoped declaration in a module, so you can't use it with role groups. How can you write a module for a role group?

Answer (score 9):

You can have modules without `unit` scoped declarations in them and export symbols from it, but how you export a role group is a bit of a problem. You can't use the `is export` trait for this, as that will export the wrong types. When you refer to a role after it has been declared, you're referring to the role group, not the individual roles within it, but using `is export` on individual roles will export those individual roles, not the roles' group. Individual roles have a very different HOW from role groups and will not behave like you would normally expect roles to!

Luckily, there's a way to do this using the `EXPORT` package. Declaring the `Foo` role group in this package will give it a name of `EXPORT::DEFAULT::Foo`, which you probably don't want, so you'll want to declare it in the `MY` scope of the unit and declare a constant for it in `EXPORT::DEFAULT` instead:

```
use v6.d;

my role Foo[Int:D] {
    method is-int(::?CLASS:_: --> True)  { }
    method is-str(::?CLASS:_: --> False) { }
}
my role Foo[Str:D] {
    method is-int(::?CLASS:_: --> False) { }
    method is-str(::?CLASS:_: --> True)  { }
}

my package EXPORT::DEFAULT {
    constant Foo = ::Foo;
}
```

Now `Foo` can be imported and used OK:

```
use Foo;

say ::<Foo>:exists;       # OUTPUT: True
say try Foo[1].is-int;    # OUTPUT: True
say try Foo['ok'].is-str; # OUTPUT: True
```

Note: you can't use `::` in constant names, so to export a role group in a namespace you'll need to wrap it in another package:

```
my role Foo::Bar[Int:D] { }
my role Foo::Bar[Str:D] { }

my package EXPORT::DEFAULT {
    package Foo {
        constant Bar = Foo::Bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple, just use the default `our` scope without a surrounding `unit` anything.

`unit` was only added so that you wouldn't have to surround a whole file with `{` and `}` when there was only one `module`, `package`, `class`, `role`, or `sub` in the file.
You don't always have to use it.
In fact you never *have* to use it.

---

If you want, add a forward declaration without a parameterization.
A trait added to it will generally apply to all of the roles with the same name.

`lib/Foo/Bar.rakumod`:

```raku
use v6.d;

role Foo::Bar {…} # is export would be added here

role Foo::Bar[Int:D] {
    method is-int(::?CLASS:_: --> True)  { }
    method is-str(::?CLASS:_: --> False) { }
}
role Foo::Bar[Str:D] {
    method is-int(::?CLASS:_: --> False) { }
    method is-str(::?CLASS:_: --> True)  { }
}
```

Then when you use it, it automatically gets loaded in such a way that it is accessible by fully qualified name.

```raku
{
    use lib <lib>; # only needed because it is not installed

    use Foo::Bar;

    say Foo::Bar[ 1].is-int; # True
    say Foo::Bar[''].is-str; # True

    say Foo::Bar.^name; # Foo::Bar
}

say Foo::Bar.^name; # error: Could not find symbol 'Bar' in 'Foo'
```

In this case you can put it inside of a module statement so that you wouldn't need to write `Foo::` so often.

`lib/Foo/Bar.rakumod`:

```raku
use v6.d;

unit module Foo;

role Bar {…}

role Bar[Int:D] {
    method is-int(::?CLASS:_: --> True)  { }
    method is-str(::?CLASS:_: --> False) { }
}
role Bar[Str:D] {
    method is-int(::?CLASS:_: --> False) { }
    method is-str(::?CLASS:_: --> True)  { }
}
```

The role is still accessible as `Foo::Bar`.
I wouldn't be surprised if this resulted in the exact same code as the previous example.

The only reason to add `is export` is if you wanted it to be exported as `Bar` instead of `Foo::Bar`. This applies to both of the above examples.

---

My guess is that you thought that you always needed to use `is export`. In many cases you really don't.

```raku
unit module Foo::Bar; # default `our` scoped

our sub baz ( --> 'hello world'){}
```

```raku
use Foo::Bar;

say Foo::Bar::baz(); # hello world
# this works because it was declared as `our`
```

If you wanted to be able to just use `baz()` while having it inside of the scope of the module, *then and only then* do you need to export it.

```raku
unit module Foo::Bar;

our sub baz ( --> 'hello world') is export {}
```

```raku
use Foo::Bar;
say Foo::Bar::baz(); # hello world

# available because of `is export`
say baz(); # hello world
```

Note that I still declared it as `our` so that if someone didn't want you to export it, it is still accessible to them.

```raku
use Foo::Bar ();

# say baz(); # baz used at line 1. Did you mean 'bag'?

say Foo::Bar::baz(); # hello world
```

The whole purpose of `is export` is to remove the need to use fully qualified names for functions. That it also works for things like roles is a side benefit.

Comment: Ah, I thought `our`-scoped declarations in modules without `unit`-scoped declarations became globals for some reason. I mentioned the behaviour with `is export` because I assumed that's how people might first try to export something like this.

Comment: I think `unit module Foo` should be `unit package Foo` though. If it's a module, then if there's any existing `Foo` elsewhere, then the symbols won't merge properly if both `Foo::Bar` and `Foo` are imported.